# Why can I create an object when there is no explicitly defined constructor?

Tags: c++

I have two pieces of code:

> Piece 1:

```
class Test{
   public:

     Test(int a) {};         
};
```

> Piece 2:

```
class Test{
    public:

    Test() {};
};
```

When i want to create an array of some size with the `Test` object i have a problem. With the first piece of code i can't create the array as `Test arr[some number]`, instead i must to do `Test *arr[some number] = new Test();`

But with the second piece of code i can do `Test arr[some number]`.

Apparently, without arguments in the constructor, I can create the array without having to point to the object's memory, but if I use constructor with args, I have to point to the object's memory address and then use the arrow operator to access its methods.

Why is this happening?

Comment: *With the first piece of code i can't create the array as Test arr[some number]*. You sure can. https://ideone.com/ERa6VE

Comment: `Test *arr[some number] = new Test();` That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Why not ? @dxiv

Comment: @EduardoSebastiánC. Try it, and the compiler will tell you exactly why.

Comment: @RSahu I'm sorry, I forgot a part of what I should have written. I have fix it.

Comment: @dxiv obviously  `some number` is a pseudocode, so..?

Comment: @EduardoSebastiánC. Guess you still did not [try it](https://godbolt.org/z/qrcsbd).

Comment: @RSahu That's actually using the second piece of code you're using. The OP seems to want to create an array with a constructor that accepts an argument.

Comment: @Chipster That was the first piece in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63571976/1) before OP's edit.

Comment: @Chipster, the OP updated their post. I copied their posted code in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From logical point of view, which permeates C++ language rules:

1. Constructors of class describes ways one object of class-type can be created.
2. If any user-defined constructor was provided,  compiler would not generate default constructor. If no constructors defined, compiler would generate copy, move  and default constructors.

Results in:

3. If there is no default constructor, object cannot be created by default initialization. Because there is no constructor for that.

To allow object be created that way, user should specify constructor for default initialization.

```
class Test{
   public:
     Test() = default;
     Test(int a) {};         
};
```

Note that array is another object, consisting of objects that are its elements. It still can be value-initialized, e.g.

```
 Test a1[3] = {3,5,7}; // those values are  passed to constructors of individual elements

 // or
 Test a2[3] = {{3},{5},{7}};
```

But if Test doesn't have a default constructor, i.e. it cannot be default initialized, code would be ill-formed if count of elements in list would be smaller than size of array.

```
 Test a[13] = {3,5,7}; // for elements 3-12 Test() will be called
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a test example from [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Gqej6s)

Here's the actual code:

```
class Test1 {
public:
    Test1() {}
};

class Test2 {
public:
    Test2(int a) {}
};

int main() {
    // Compiles just fine
    Test1 test1Arr[5];

    // Fails to Compile
    Test2 test2Arr[5];

    return 0;
}
```

Now, this fails to compile because of the 2nd case... If we comment `Test2 test2Arr[5];` so that it compiles it will generate this assembly for `gcc 10.2`...

```
Test1::Test1() [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    r12
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, [rbp-21]
        mov     ebx, 4
        mov     r12, rax
.L4:
        test    rbx, rbx
        js      .L3
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    Test1::Test1() [complete object constructor]
        add     r12, 1
        sub     rbx, 1
        jmp     .L4
.L3:
        mov     eax, 0
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbx
        pop     r12
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

So as you can see you can create an `array` of `class` or `struct` objects with default constructors easily.

The reason it is failing in the other case is that it is not a default constructor. You have an `explicit` argument making it a user-defined constructor and you have not declared a default constructor.

In other words, if you were to create a single instance of this class object you must pass an argument to its constructor.

```
Test2 test2(3);
```

Now since you want to create an array of these and without using `dynamic` memory, you can take advantage of `brace-initialization`

If you were to do this:

```
Test2 testArra[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
```

This will compile and this will generate the following assembly:

```
Test1::Test1() [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
Test2::Test2(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], esi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    r12
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, [rbp-21]
        mov     ebx, 4
        mov     r12, rax
.L5:
        test    rbx, rbx
        js      .L4
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    Test1::Test1() [complete object constructor]
        add     r12, 1
        sub     rbx, 1
        jmp     .L5
.L4:
        lea     rbx, [rbp-26]
        mov     esi, 0
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    Test2::Test2(int)
        add     rbx, 1
        mov     esi, 1
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    Test2::Test2(int)
        add     rbx, 1
        mov     esi, 2
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    Test2::Test2(int)
        add     rbx, 1
        mov     esi, 3
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    Test2::Test2(int)
        lea     rax, [rbx+1]
        mov     esi, 4
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    Test2::Test2(int)
        mov     eax, 0
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbx
        pop     r12
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

This works because it will assign each value of the `brace-initialization` through the use of the `comma-operator` to each element of the `array`'s user-defined constructor...

Now, if you define both constructors within the same class as such:

```
class Test3 {
public:
    Test3() {}
    Test3(int a) {}
};

int main() {
    Test3 test3Arr[5];

    return 0;
}
```

This will compile generating this assembly code:

```
Test3::Test3() [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    r12
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, [rbp-21]
        mov     ebx, 4
        mov     r12, rax
.L4:
        test    rbx, rbx
        js      .L3
        mov     rdi, r12
        call    Test3::Test3() [complete object constructor]
        add     r12, 1
        sub     rbx, 1
        jmp     .L4
.L3:
        mov     eax, 0
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbx
        pop     r12
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

which can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nb7edn).

The bottom line is... when you declare-define a user-defined constructor, the compiler will not automatically generate a default constructor for you and if you want that behavior you must define it yourself. Now, if you do not have any user-defined constructors and everything is default initialized, then you don't have to define any constructor and the compiler will automatically generate the default constructor for you.

Comment: `Test3() {}` Or just `Test3() = default;`.

Comment: @dxiv True, but I was using conventional constructors and didn't want to overburden the `OP` with `= default` semantics just yet as it appears that they are new to the language and is trying to learn the basics. I feel that sugar coating things to beginners is a bad way for them to learn. When I first learned about classes, their constructors, and destructors there was no `= default` or  `= delete`. Then again, when I first started to learn C++ there was no such thing as `smart-pointers` either, everything had to be done manually and you had to take into account everything...

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment. However, and besides the more technical points, the `= default;` construct also helps dispel the notion that you somehow "lose" something by defining a parameterized constructor - "*the compiler had a default constructor ready made for me, but now it's gone*". Fact is that it's not gone, just hidden, and `= default;` brings it back and makes it accessible again.

Comment: @dxiv True, but now we're just getting into semantics and each compiler may handle this differently too... GCC versus Clang versus MSVC versus Intel, etc... as they might implement it differently, however, they all should be somewhat similar since they do have to follow the standard.

Comment: @FrancisCugler eh, MSVC was literally making empty default constructor until recent versions (i.e.  there was no difference  between its default and empty user-defined one, the value initialization of class would result in default-initialization of its members)